# How can I configure a Jekyll build to publish to a Github Pages root?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

#### Summary

I want to update my GitHub Pages site so that its root, http://keithwegner.github.io hosts a Jekyll blog. Its currently returning a HTTP 404, and the working blog being set at http://keithwegner.github.io/blog

#### Background

I have a Github repo at http://github.com/keithwegner. I've been playing around with Jekyll (only a few hours), and ran through a [tutorial](http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/building-static-sites-with-jekyll-github-pages) demonstrating a simple Jekyll blog lifecycle, from dependencies, configuration, serving locally, to finally publishing to GitHub Pages.  It also gave a cursory review of the key gem and YML files.

The tutorial updates the _config.yml file to update these properties FROM this:

```
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "localhost:4000" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
```

TO this:

```
baseurl: "/blog" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "localhost:4000" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
```

Here is the provided rational:

> **baseurl**: Fill in the quotation marks with a forward slash followed by the name of your website folder (e.g. “/blog”) to help locate the
>   site at the correct URL.

And this:

> The changes you made to the baseurl and url lines will let your site
>   run from the same files both locally on your computer and live on the
>   Web, but doing this changed the URL where you’ll see your local site
>   from now on (while Jekyll is running) from localhost:4000 to
>   localhost:4000/JekyllDemo/ (substitute your website folder name for
>   JekyllDemo and remembering the last slash mark)

The tutorial's initial commit to my [blog](http://www.github.com/keithwegner/blog) repo publishes to a `gh-pages` branch. This allows the following url to resolve the blog: http://keithwegner.github.io/blog, but navigating to http://keithwegner.github.io returns a 404.

#### Approaches

I thought that a recent [commit](https://github.com/keithwegner/blog/blob/1c0ae50fcb20c0e0d9b9ed50210ea1f76bacfe1e/_config.yml) to update `baseurl: ""` would resolve this, but its still working as I've initially described. Also, running on localhost:4000 works, which was my quick-and-dirty test before committing.

Clearly I'm missing something about the Jekyll build process or how GitHub Pages work. So, any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Your repo is named "blog", so your site is served at the subpath "/blog" (a Project Pages site). To serve it at root (a User Pages site) you need to rename your repo to keithwegner.github.io. https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Comment: @approxiblue you can set this comment as an answer and add the fact that any project repository can be linked to a custom domain and become root of this domain.

Comment: Thanks @approxiblue. I do recognize that important distinction, and should have probably mentioned that in my troubleshooting, I had also tried setting it to a User Pages site, i.e., publishing the whole repo to keithwegner.github.io. Oddly, it continued exhibiting the same behavior. (I run a company page off Pages, so I'm somewhat familiar with it).

So, just so I'm crystal clear -- a straightforward creation of `jekyll new keithwegner.github.io` and then publishing it immediately to github _should_ work, without having to make any config changes in the _config.yml_?

Comment: @DavidJacquel, thanks for the additional clarification. That's actually what my other corporate page does.

Comment: Yeah, so for your current blog repo, if you push that to `keithwegner.github.io`, branch master (not gh-pages like a project site), it should work.

Comment: @approxiblue thanks. I must have forgotten to rebuild or hadn't updated something in the config before publishing. Should be easy...